# Why does Chromium connect to Google on startup?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I installed Chromium on Ubuntu from the official repositories. I

- disabled everything in the "Privacy" section
- am not logged in
- set my default search to duckduckgo
- set my first page to an empty tab

Then I closed Chromium, launched Wireshark, started a capture and opened Chromium again.
After a few seconds I saw an https connection to 173.194.40.83, which is a Google IP.

Why does Chromium connect to Google at every startup? Unfortunately it's an SSL connection so I can't see what is being sent. Is there any way to see the unencrypted content of that traffic?

Comment: Have you tried to open chrome://net-internals/#events ?
I guess, it must be done BEFORE chromium connects to google. Not sure about this.

Comment: I see a `URL_REQUEST` to [https://www.google.com/searchdomaincheck?format=url&type=chrome](https://www.google.com/searchdomaincheck?format=url&type=chrome) and then a `SOCKET` to `ssl/www.google.com:443`

Comment: If it is only url, chromium connects at startup, you should't worry.
Otherwise you can just block all connections to google via firewall.

Comment: Do you know what this request is for?

Comment: It lets chromium to find default search domain for google (for example, google.co.uk, if user is from UK). I do now know why it sends this request, if you set another default search engine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The page [*searchdomaincheck*](https://www.google.com/searchdomaincheck?format=url&type=chrome) returns your preferred Google domain. For me, visiting it returns `https://www.google.com/` normally, but `https://www.google.com.py/` in a temporary profile and incognito mode.

This is its main function, although I fail to see why it is needed if you're not using the Google search engine. To make this possible, Chromium has to be sending your Google cookies.

The request to *searchdomaincheck* is made by the [GoogleURLTracker](https://github.com/darwin/chromium-src-chrome-browser/blob/master/google/google_url_tracker.h) class, which says in its comments:

```
// This object is responsible for checking the Google URL once per network
// change, and if necessary prompting the user to see if they want to change to
// using it.  The current and last prompted values are saved to prefs.
```

A "network change" will be detected, e.g., by the function `OnIPAddressChanged()`.

I'm desperately trying not to behave tinfoilhattish here, but this sounds like a cheap way to associate a tracking cookie with an IP address.

According to [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), the command-line switch `--google-search-domain-check-url` should be able to stop this behavior.

Try invoking Chromium as follows:

```
chromium-browser --google-search-domain-check-url=localhost
```

Comment: I will report this as a bug to the chromium devs.

Comment: If it is of any help, I wrote an extension with which a user can see (and optionally block) all net requests, **including** those made behind the scene like the above _searchdomaincheck_. Cookies can also be stripped from outgoing headers, etc. Name: [HTTP Switchboard](https://github.com/gorhill/httpswitchboard). Works on any Chromium-based browser.

Comment: That command-line switch appears to no longer be listed on that link

Comment: The relevant switch is now `--gaia-url=`. Note, passing `--disable-gaia-services` contrary to expectation does _not_ disable the ping.